# Cómo puedo insertar mediante mongoose un objeto que tiene objetos?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose, reactjs

```
[{
    "nombre": "compra",
    "datos": [{
        "id": "5a1779d7563db4850df90d99",
        "nombre": "Papas",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "precio": "3150",
        "total": "3150"
    }, {
        "id": "5a179ffa1fcdfe2af8e9662c",
        "nombre": "Peras",
        "cantidad": 1,
        "precio": "4500",
        "total": "4500"
    }]
}]
```

Este de acá es mi objeto, el que estoy enviando a mongoose mediante éste código

```
exports.add = function(req, res) {
    console.log('POST');

    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body.datos));    
    var dataTable = new DataTable({
         nombre : req.body.nombre,       
         datos : req.body.datos
    });

    console.log(dataTable);

    dataTable.save(function(err, dataTable) {
        if(err) return res.send(500, err.message);
        res.status(200).jsonp(dataTable);
    });

};
```

El console.log(req.body) me arroja el objeto como el primero que muestro y el problema es que no sé cómo colocarlo en el objeto dataTable para que quede como en este ejemplo de mongoose que encontré:

```
db.genbetadev.insert(
{
    name:"Tyrion",
    friends:
    [
        {name:"Bronn", ocuppation:"sellsword"},
        {name:"Shae", ocuppation:"handmaiden"}
    ]
}
```

Yo sé que mediante la consola de mongo se puede insertar pero, ¿Cómo hago para poder insertarlo mediante mongoose?

Comment: Debes poner lo que has intentado para poder ayudarte, algo de mongoose por lo menos

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que hacer require de los datos tal y como los estás enviando

```
exports.add = function(req, res) {
console.log('POST');

console.log(req.body);
console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body.datos));    
var dataTable = new DataTable({
     nombre : req.body.nombre,       
     datos : [{ //modelo para inserción de datos
         id : req.body.id,
         nombre : req.body.nombre, //trata de no repetir el tipo de dato en un elemento hijo
         cantidad : req.body.cantidad, 
         precio : req.body.precio, 
         total: req.body.total
     }]
});

console.log(dataTable);

dataTable.save(function(err, dataTable) {
    if(err) return res.send(500, err.message);
    res.status(200).jsonp(dataTable);
});
};
```

ya que `Datos` es un arreglo, tienes que enviar objeto por objeto